# Custom templates in CKEditor

Tags: javascript, templates, ckeditor

I'm trying to load some custom templates in CKEditor but I can't manage to make it work.

This is the part of the config.js dealing with custom templates:

```
config.templates = 'default';
config.templates_files = [ '/mytemplates/mytemplates.js' ];
config.templates_replaceContent = false;
```

I've created a `/mytemplates` folder inside the root of the CKEditor folder and put the `mytemplates.js` (an exact copy of the `default.js` file that comes with the content templates plugin) inside it, but it seems the editor is not loading them. I'm getting the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagesPath' of undefined` in the `imagesPath = definition.imagesPath,` line of the `/plugins/templates/dialogs/templates.js` file.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix this using the `CKEDITOR.getUrl()` function:

```
config.templates_files = [ CKEDITOR.getUrl( 'mytemplates/mytemplates.js' ) ];
```

I don't know if there's a way to use custom templates placed outside the CKEditor folder. If so, post a comment here, please.

Thanks

Comment: Path to templates file you used was relative and probably not valid for CKEditor current dir, `CKEDITOR.getUrl()` is a good approach. To load file from outside CKEditor directory you may just use a full URL (like `http://yourdomain.com/.../mytemplates.js`) or proper relative URL (you can see in browser dev console if the file is loading correctly).

Comment: Thanks for your insight!